# Call remote ejb from camel route

Tags: apache-camel, ejb-3.1, apache-servicemix

I'd like to create osgi bundle which listen for soap messages and route them to remote ejb. I have servicemix 4.x as a bundle environment, glassfish 4 as a ejb container and camel as routing engine. Is it possible to connect to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there `cxf` and `ejb` components and you should be able to define your route like this:

```
from("cxf:...")
    // ...
    .to(ejb:...")
;
```

Please refer to: [Apache Camel Components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) - CXF and EJB.

Comment: The problem is that ejb is on the different jvm, so I must define host and port or jndi registry somewhere.